# Iphone: How to get all attributes of a class?

Tags: iphone, reflection, runtime

I have this class:

```
@interface Mission : BaseModel  
{
NSString  *Description;
NSDate  *EndDate;
NSMutableArray  *MissionSectionList;
NSString  *Name;
NSDate  *StartDate;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString  *Description;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate  *EndDate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray  *MissionSectionList;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString  *Name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate  *StartDate;
@end
```

Is it possible to find out all the atrributes of this class?
I tried it with

> Ivar class_getClassVariable(Class cls, const char* name)

But I don't know what the name should be:

> name: The name of the class variable definition to obtain.

And actually I want to get all of them without knowing the name.

Is this possible?

Comment: What about making a method that will return an array with these attributes? But it's probably a bad way to do it :)

Comment: what info about the attributes are you trying to find? It says you dont want the name, do you want to know what type they are?

Comment: I actually want the name and the type. I was not sure what the param name is for. Because I want to find out the name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `class_copyIvarList` function to get the list of all instance variables of the class. Then you can iterate through it to get attributes of each ivar. (Note that you're responsible for freeing memory used for ivars array). Sample code may look like:

```
unsigned int count;
Ivar *varList = class_copyIvarList([Mission class],&count);
for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i){
    Ivar var = varList[i];
    // Do when you need with ivar
}
free(varList);
```

Comment: Thank you! How can I output var? I Did  NSLog(@"MY ATTR: %@",var); but it says EXC_BAD_ACCES.

Comment: Ivar is a pointer to a structure, not an obj-c class - you can't output it directly using NSLog. Use ivar_getName,ivar_getTypeEncoding
, ivar_getOffset functions to get iVar properties.